# How can I change the logo in a zopeskel plone3_theme?

Tags: themes, plone

I tried adding this to the browser/configure.zcml

```
  <browser:resource
      name="logo.jpg"
      file="images/logo.png"
      layer=".interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
      />
```

But that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

For what I remember plone3_theme themes use CMF Skin technology, not browser resources.

You must simply put your new logo (with the same name as the old one) in the `skins/xxx_custom_images/` directory

As the logo is loaded from the Plone site root, the existing skins directory "win" over your browser resource. See https://dev.plone.org/ticket/9284

However you can also use a logo with a new id (and then put it in the browser directory). In this case you must configure the `base_properties.props` inside the `skins/xxx_styles` directory.